# jQuery - Disabling function when animation is running

Tags: jquery, function, scroll

I'm using the code below to add classes on scroll to an sticky nav bar. It works fine but I want it to disable the scroll functions when and li element in the nav bar is clicked so it doesn't start changing classes when the scrolling animation after the user clicked on the nav started so I guess I need to disable the scroll functions untill the scrolling animation is done. Any suggestions?

EDIT
Maybe I'm unclear here.
I use an scrolling animation when the user clicks a li item. I also use an function that will add the active class if the user scrolls past the div the li item is for. When an user is at the top of the page now and clicks one of the li items the active class will be added first to the li they clicked on and then to all the li items after that but I want it to stay on only the li item they clicked on so maybe I need to disable the adding the active class on scroll function untill the scroll animation from the click is done?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop(),
    nav_distance = 450,
    grid_3_distance = $("section.grid.third").offset().top - 1,
    grid_4_distance = $("section.grid.fourth").offset().top - 230;

    if(top > nav_distance) {
        $("section.grid.second ul").addClass("fixed");
    } else if(top < nav_distance) {
        $("section.grid.second ul").removeClass("fixed");
    }

    if(top > nav_distance){
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li").removeClass("active");
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li[data-intern='.grid.second']").addClass("active");
    }

    if(top > grid_3_distance){
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li").removeClass("active");
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li[data-intern='.grid.third']").addClass("active");
    }

    if(top > grid_4_distance){
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li").removeClass("active");
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li[data-intern='.grid.fourth']").addClass("active");
    }
});

$(function(){
    $("section.grid.second ul nav li").click(function(){
        $("section.grid.second ul nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var id = $(this).attr("data-intern");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(id).offset().top}, 500);
    });
```

Comment: I'd suggest you just go ahead and do what you have described. It is not clear from your question which part you have difficulties with.

Comment: I edited the question to make myself more clear. I hope you understand better what I'm trying to do here now.

Comment: jQuery has an [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) which might help you.

Comment: Could you duplicate your problem in a jsFiddle?